# Why does my layout file not link up to my spinner?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I was trying to make a custom spinner but for some reason, my layout file is not getting linked up properly.
It appears in red.
custom_spinner and custom_spinner_dropdown are the two layout files

Layout file code:
custom_spinner-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textSize="20sp"
   android:gravity="left"
   android:fontFamily="@font/baloo_chettan"
   style="?android:dropDownItemStyle"
   android:textColor="#FBFAFA"
   android:padding="5dip"
   android:singleLine="true"
   android:background="@drawable/box"


   />
```

custom_spinner_dropdown-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"

    android:fontFamily="@font/baloo_chettan"
    style="?android:dropDownItemStyle"
    android:textColor="#FBFAFA"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:background="@drawable/box"
    android:textAlignment="center"


    />
```

Spinner code:

```
        ArrayAdapter<String> myMeal =new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity2.this,android.R.layout.custom_spinner,getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Meal));
        myMeal.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.custom_spinner_dropdown);
        meal.setAdapter(myMeal);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `android.R.layout.custom_spinner` is a problem. Why do you use `android.` prefix? Using `android.` means using standard library resources. Try deleting `android.`

```java
ArrayAdapter<String> myMeal =new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity2.this, R.layout.custom_spinner, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Meal));
```